# How to build an image with every pixel's RGB value

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am using Python and the PIL library and I have the RGB information for every pixel of an image along with their location.  Is there any way that I can build an image from this information?

Comment: How is the information currently represented?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. If your source data is sparse (ie. you don't have a value for every pixel location) you probably want to do the following:

- create an empty image of the required dimensions
- ensure your colour data is stored in raster order (ie. sort by y then x)
- iterate through the data and store the pixel values in each location

So, assuming you have an array of tuples such as `(x, y, (r,g,b))`, you can do something like:

```
from pil import Image

WIDTH=640
HEIGHT=480

img = Image.new(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 'RGB')

# Define this based on your data
my_raster_sort(my_image_data)

img_data = img.load()
for x, y, color in my_image_data:
    img_data[x,y] = color
```

If your source image data is complete (ie. you have a colour value for every position) then it would probably be faster to transform your data into a buffer formatted with the desired memory layout, and then create an image in one step using [`Image.frombuffer`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's what `Image.putpixel()` (and possibly `putdata()` depending on how you have the data) are for. Find the documentation for these methods [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm).

Hard to advise you further since you provided no code or even a sample of the data.

Comment: Documentation link is broken :(